# $facebook->api callback function?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

anyone know of a callback function I can call after I have done a FB api call using the PHP SDK?

If not, is there some way I can build one into the SDK?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't necessary, as all calls to the Facebook Graph API via the PHP SDK are **synchronous**. Therefore you can call any function directly after the call to the API, consider this example:

```
<?php

try {
    $result = $facebook->api("/me");
    do_something($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Log Error
}
```

Also the PHP-SDK is Open Source, so you could also fork it, implement your feature and file a Pull Request on Github with your changes. You can find the Source at https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk.

Answer (score 2):

Put the API call in a try/catch statement...

```
try {
    $facebook->api(array(
        'query' => $query,
        'method' => 'fql.query'
    ));
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo 'An error occured!';
}

// Assume it has worked as the exception has not been caught
echo "It worked!";
```