# How to get place_id before checkin?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, checkin

My app lets users checkin with lat, lon and place name to Facebook. But I don't know how to deal with "place" parameter.

Is there any way to get or create one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Each checkinable place must have a valid Place Facebook Page.**

The `place` parameter takes in the `page_id` of a Place Facebook Page.

For example, `page_id` 104999729569954 of Place Facebook Page http://www.facebook.com/pages/Nanyang-Polytechnic/104999729569954

---

**If your application is letting your users to checkin based on their current location**

1) Use an external map service such as Google Map's Geolocation to get the coordinates(lat & lon) of your user's current location.

***The set of coordinates returned from Google Map is different from Facebook's own set of coordinates.***

2) To overcome this, do a FQL query to find the closest match of Facebook's coordinates with Google Map's coordinates.

`SELECT page_id,latitude,longitude FROM place WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, "LAT_HERE", "LON_HERE") < 250`

`250` refers to the radius(m) that it will search within, it can go up to `50000`.

3) Now that you have `page_id`, `latitude` and `longitude`. Assign `page_id` into `place` parameter. Assign `latitude` and `longitude` into `coordinates` parameter. You will then be able to publish checkin.

You can refer to publish checkin examples that I have posted over here. [Facebook - Publish Checkins using PHP SDK/JavaScript SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072933/facebook-publish-checkins-using-php-sdk-javascript-sdk/11101740#11101740)

---

**If your application is letting your users to checkin based on selection from a list of place names or gallery of images** (in a game or something)

You will just need to find the `page_id` of each place and bind them to respective place name or image.

---

**Documentation**

Page FQL - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/

Checkins API - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#checkins

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want.
Open graph explorer Just replace URL with any facebook page url

[fql?q=SELECT id FROM object_url WHERE url="https://www.facebook.com/LegendCinema"](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)