# Facebook PHP SDK : Post a Check in without a PAGE_ID

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I would like to know If it's possible to add a Check in on Facebook with PHP but without any Page id.

Because I have a database with a lot of places but I do not have a corresponding Facebook Page Id.

ANy idea?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, it is not possible to do a Check In without a `page_id`.

You can refer to [How to get place_id before checkin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828940/how-to-get-place-id-before-checkin/11882689#11882689) to find out how to get Facebook Page Id for your places.

Comment: I actually found by myself what I was looking for. I created an action on Facebook